# Stripe is taking away the credits if 3DS authentication is not completed

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe subscription with PHP and have 2 products that can be subscribed to monthly & yearly. Let's say a usr is subscribed to $11 monthly and on the same day he upgrades to $100 yearly. In this case, if the payment is processed successfully, he has to pay $89 ($100 - $11). Now if I initiate the payment, goes till the 3ds authentication and close the window and re-try to subscribe to yearly product, the credits are gone! It's no longer showing credits. Here's the code that I'm using for updating the subscription.

```
$subscription_data = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subscription_id);

$stripe2 = new \Stripe\StripeClient(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

$updatedSubscription = $stripe2->subscriptions->update(
      $subscription_id,
      [
        'items' => [
          [
            'id' => $subscription_item_id,
            'price' => $yearly_price_id,
          ],
        ],
        'off_session' => true
      ]
    );
```

Comment: Normally, it should use the saved payment method (same that you used to pay $11), without needing for customer to be present on session. Is it not the case for you? How are you creating a new payment session after you make the `subscriptions->update()` call? Maybe the Subscription is already updated.

Comment: Checked that in the first place. Even if you save your card, with some banks or with some type of amount, 3ds might be required.

Comment: Sounds like Pending Updates might help in this use-case. It will automatically revert the subscription to its previous state if the payment doesn't succeed.
https://docs.stripe.com/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates